# Security Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Here i have published my MVC web application, but it can't open due to the Security Exception Error.
[image]

I have tried to use `<trust level="Full" />` and `<securityPolicy>` as well. If i applied one of these to solve Security Exception, it show Configuration Error:
[image]

I would appreciate your help, if you have an alternative way to solve this problem.

Comment: Check the configuration error details by browsing this page in a Windows session on the server.

Comment: Many web hosts won't allow you to change the trust level.  Are you certain yours allows it?

Comment: Or set <customErrors mode="Off"/> temporarily

Comment: Andreas Pilavakis **Thanks** - even I added `<customErrors mode="Off" /> is not working. If am not mistaken the customErrors is not related with Security Error because anyway it used for customizing Error. So i want to be able to Solve Error not to customize it.

Comment: Do you locate your site in C:\inetpub\wwwroot ?

Comment: Lance,
Yes website is in ..\wwwroot
In the File Manager of the host right

Comment: The error essentially means that there is at machine.config level (or on parent web.config level if you're hosting your app as child application on IIS) locked this section - preventing you from changing it at child level. Where do you host your application, do you have control over parent config ?

Comment: Thanks **Ondrej**,  I hosted the website at web hosting called WebAfrica, i don't understand how is that possible.

Comment: Well you'll have to talk to your hosting provider about that - I guess they disabled this on purpose - cheap hosting sites doesn't grant you separate VM - you share one box with other web applications & they force security rules (such as prohibition of using reflection) so you can't break other site that is being hosted there. Also you can move to different provider.

Comment: @Ondrej One way to check your point of view is to IIS and Configuration Editor. If you have set locked properties, it will crashed and said that there are errors in the config file

Comment: Can you share your web.config ?

Comment: Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595645/security-exception-when-trying-to-view-mvc-website-on-go-daddy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595645/security-exception-when-trying-to-view-mvc-website-on-go-daddy)

Comment: The error that you get when you try to change the trust level is because your hosting provider has disallowed you changing that setting via your applications configuration.

Ive given up on shared hosting providers because of issues like this, Odds are your initial issue is because the provider is blocking something (HTTP Modules are often an issue)

Comment: Are you using return Json()? If so you might get a similar error is you don't add allow get for GET's return Json(JsonBehavior.AllowGet);

Answer (score 0):

This sounds much  like, security issue that your IIS is experiencing, can you see is your web application have rights to the folder or  your Application pool?

Answer (score 0):

Enable `anonymous authentication mode` in `project properties`
and in the `Web.Config` file add

```
add key="enableSimpleMembership" to value="true"
add key="autoFormsAuthentication" to  value="true"
```

Hope it will work.